# Показать input'ты по клику на textarea?

Tags: jquery

Доброго дня, есть такая форма:

```
<input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30" placeholder="Имя"/>
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" placeholder="Email"/>
<input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="" size="30" placeholder="Сайт"/>
<textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true" placeholder="Текст комментария..."></textarea>
<p class="form-submit">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить" />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='134' id='comment_post_ID' />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0' />
</p>
```

Выглядит так: http://ssmaker.ru/c621cbf6.png

Не понимаю как сделать, чтобы по умолчанию все input'ты были скрыты, а по клику на textarea показывались.

то есть по началу так: http://ssmaker.ru/ccc378a7.png

А когда нажали так: http://ssmaker.ru/c621cbf6.png

Comment: Безотносительно технической реализации: так делать не надо. Сделайте тогда кнопку «добавить комментарий» — и показывайте все поля, а её прячьте. Элементы надо использовать для того, для чего они предназначены. Иначе у пользователя сложится мнение, что чтобы оставить комментарий ему надо написать только текст комментария, а на деле это не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да хоть так

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('textarea#comment').click(function() {
    $('.form-hidden').show();
  });

  $(document).click(function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if (!$target.parents('.form').length) {
      $('.form-hidden').hide();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.form-hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form">
  <div class="form-hidden">
    <input id="author" name="author" type="text" value="" size="30" placeholder="Имя" />
    <input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30" placeholder="Email" />
    <input id="url" name="url" type="text" value="" size="30" placeholder="Сайт" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" aria-required="true" placeholder="Текст комментария..."></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="form-hidden form-submit">
    <input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" value="Отправить" />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment_post_ID' value='134' id='comment_post_ID' />
    <input type='hidden' name='comment_parent' id='comment_parent' value='0' />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: То что надо, спасибо! Только как сделать, чтобы все возвращалось (скрывалось) если произошел клик в какую то другую область, а не в textarea?

Comment: обновил код, теперь скрывается